# awakeFromNib Returning Null UILabel Values

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uilabel, awakefromnib

I am using a custom cell inside my table view. I have a view and I have a button inside that view that when the cell loads it checks if the array contains a labels text inside the cell. When I try get the text of a label it returns an empty value, if I click the button which has the same method to get the text contained it works just fine and gives me the text of the label.

Attached is the code

```
#import "TableViewCellSchedule.h"

@implementation TableViewCellSchedule
@synthesize name = _name;
@synthesize time = _time;
@synthesize pic = _pic;
@synthesize text = _text;
@synthesize scheduleID = _scheduleID;
NSMutableArray *favid;

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    // Initialization code
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    favid = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *temparray = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"favid"];
    if(temparray.count > 0){
        favid = [temparray mutableCopy];
        if([temparray containsObject:self.scheduleID.text]){
            NSLog(@"set image here, id is: %@", self.scheduleID.text);
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"change image back here, id is: %@", self.scheduleID.text);
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"welcome, array is: %@", favid);
}
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (IBAction)addfav {

    if([favid containsObject:self.scheduleID.text]){
        NSLog(@"contained already");
    }
    else{
         NSLog(@"not contained");
        [favid addObject:self.scheduleID.text];
        NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [userDefaults setObject:favid forKey:@"favid"];
        [userDefaults synchronize];
    }
    //NSLog(@"schedule id is: %@", self.scheduleID.text);
    //NSLog(@"fav log: %@", favid);
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `scheduleID` label is not yet constructed and assigned the value to , you can do this by creating a property to hold the same value and set it in `cellForRowAt` **OR** move that whole check code in cellForRow and compare the value that should be assigned to the label directly with the array